# How do I collect user input inside an array in Java and print then out using classes

Tags: java, arrays, user-input

Finish the program.  It needs to:

create and fill an array based on user input
display the array
rotate the elements to the right (move elements to the next index, and the last element to the first index)
display the rotated array

Example input/output
Input
3 // number of elements
2
4
6

Output
2 4 6
6 2 4

What my code is so far (it's a mess)

```
import java.util.*;
class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] array = makeArray();
    display(array);
    rotateRight(array);
    display(array);
  }
  /*Create an array of user-defined size.
   *Fill the array with use input
   *return the created and filled array*/
  public static int[] makeArray()
  {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int numberOfElements = input.nextInt();
    
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfElements; i++)
    {
      array[i] = input.nextInt();
    } 
      return array;
  }
  /*display all elements in the array*/
  public static void display(int[] arr)
  {
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
    {
      System.out.println(arr[i]);
    }
  }
  /*move every element to the next position and the last element to the first position*/
  public static void rotateRight(int[] arr)
  {
    
    return;
  }
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question to make the instructions clearer. then explain what problem you are having. What is the expected result and what is actually happening?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an array inside `makeArry` explicitly by using the `new` operator and then allocate enough memory for the number of elements that you want to store in that array. In this case, you can read the total number of items from the keyboard in the first place and use that value to create the array. For instance, you just need to change your code like this:

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] array = makeArray();
    display(array);
    System.out.println();
    rotateRight(array);
    System.out.println();
    display(array);
  }

  /**
   * Create an array of user-defined size. Fill the array with use input return the created and
   * filled array
   */
  public static int[] makeArray() {
    System.out.print("Enter number of elements: ");
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    // Initialize an array with the required size
    int numberOfElements = input.nextInt();
    int[] array = new int[numberOfElements];
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfElements; i++) {
      array[i] = input.nextInt();
    }
    return array;
  }

  /**
   * display all elements in the array
   */
  public static void display(int[] arr) {
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      System.out.printf("%d ", arr[i]);
    }
  }

  /**
   * Move every element to the next position and the last element to the first position
   */
  public static void rotateRight(int[] arr) {
    int last = arr[arr.length - 1];
    for (int i = arr.length - 2; i >= 0; i--) {
      arr[i + 1] = arr[i];
    }
    arr[0] = last;
  }
}
```

Comment: I would recommend explaining what is happening in the `rotateRight` method, as it can be extremely confusing to beginners.